# Accessing data required out of for loop in python and store the data at specific location

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I am using a for loop for getting data from the user in command prompt using python 2.7. Then storing the data in a text file in certain format. I am looking for a method to get the data from the user and store it in a list and use it where required.

```
  for Input_Number in range(Number_Of_Inputs):
         Input_Number = Input_Number+1
         GUI_Parameter = str(raw_input("Please enter input parameter " + str(Input_Number) + " :"))
         GUI_Parameter_Name = str(raw_input("Enter the GUI name for the parameter " +                  str(Input_Number) + " :"))
         Store_GUI_Parameter(Opened_File, GUI_Parameter, GUI_Parameter_Name)
```

I would like to use this data to store it in a specific location in a text file according to required syntax. The above code stores the data in the text file. But the problem is it doesn't store it at the required place.

```
def Store_GUI_Parameter(Opened_File, GUI_Parameter, GUI_Parameter_Name):
    GUI_Description = "| " + '"'+ GUI_Parameter_Name + '"' + " |$" + GUI_Parameter.title() + " |"
    Write_Data(Opened_File, GUI_Description)
    print "GUI parameters written to NDF file"
    return
```

The data storage is done using the above function...

I tried this, but unfortunately this also is not working

```
 GUI_Parameter= []
 GUI_Parameter_Name = []
 for Input_Number in range(Number_Of_Inputs):
        Input_Number = Input_Number+1
        GUI_Parameter[Input_Number] = str(raw_input("Please enter input parameter " + str(Input_Number) + " :"))
        GUI_Parameter_Name[Input_Number] = str(raw_input("Enter the GUI name for the parameter " + str(Input_Number) + " :"))
```

Using it outside the loop in the same function...

```
 GUI_Description(Opened_File, GUI_Parameter_Name[Input_Number], GUI_Parameter[Input_Number])
```

The function implementation:

```
def GUI_Description(Opened_File, GUI_Parameter_Name[Input_Number], GUI_Parameter[Input_Number]):
    Iteration = 0
    while Iteration < Input_Number:
        Iteration += 1
        GUI_Description = "| " + '"'+ GUI_Parameter_Name[Input_Number] + '"' + " |$" + GUI_Parameter[Input_Number].title() + " |"
        Write_Data(Opened_File, GUI_Description)
        print "GUI parameters written to NDF file"
    return
```

But it shows syntax error at the `def GUI_Description`

> C:\Users\padmanab\Desktop>python CtoN.py   File "CtoN.py", line 173
>       def GUI_Description(Opened_File, GUI_Parameter_Name[Input_Number], GUI_Parameter[Input_Number]):
>                                                          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Post full error message.

Comment: HI @NewWorld I have updated the error message ...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error in the function GUI_Description is caused by your input arguments. 'GUI_Parameter_Name[Input_Number]' is not a valid input argument. Since your function requires both 'GUI_Parameter_Name' and 'Input_Number' they should be separate input arguments. The code snippet below would solve this syntax error:

```
def GUI_Description(Opened_File, Input_Number, GUI_Parameter_Name, GUI_Parameter):
    ...
```

The code below will give an 'index out of range' error since the lists 'GUI_Parameter' and 'GUI_Parameter_Name' have zero length.

```
GUI_Parameter= []
GUI_Parameter_Name = []
Number_Of_Inputs = 1
for Input_Number in range(Number_Of_Inputs):
    Input_Number = Input_Number+1
    GUI_Parameter[Input_Number] = str(raw_input("Please enter input parameter " + str(Input_Number) + " :"))
    GUI_Parameter_Name[Input_Number] = str(raw_input("Enter the GUI name for the parameter " + str(Input_Number) + " :"))
```

If you want to add items to the arrays you should append them:

```
GUI_Parameter.append(raw_input())
```